# Syntax error working with robot framework conditional statement and keyword

Tags: python, robotframework

Here am trying to find a solution to a problem, i created a code that logs into a site and check the status of the site but collecting the status of element attribute and storing it into a variable called ${class}. Now here the problem the site can be in only four states denoted by color code green, yellow, red and gray. I tried 3 solutions

1 To place each of the status into a scalar variable eg ${GREEN}=  status_indicator green and so forth then the code below follows but it didt work

```
Run Keyword If  ${GREEN} == ${class}  Keyword green
...  ELSE IF  ${YELLOW} == ${class}  Keyword yellow
...  ELSE IF  ${RED} == ${class}  Keyword red
...  ELSE  Keyword gray
```

2 i placed them into a list eg @{COLOR}=  status_indicator green and so forth
then tried this

```
list should contain value  @{COLOR}  ${class}
```

In my opinion what will work best is a conditional statement since it words with the keywords i have created Please advice on what i should do thanks.

Comment: what does "it didn't work" mean? Did it throw an error? Did it do the wrong thing?

Comment: Yes it throws an error  "Evaluating expression 'status_indicator green == status_indicator green' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)                                                     "

Comment: Run Keyword If  @{COLOR}[0] == ${class}  Keyword green
    ...  ELSE IF  @{COLOR}[1] == ${class}  Keyword yellow
    ...  ELSE IF  @{COLOR}[2] == ${class}  Keyword red
    ...  ELSE  Keyword gray

Comment: please don't post code in the comment section. Instead, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important thing to remember is that the condition is evaluated as a python expression. Robot will pass the condition directly to python after substituting the variables.

From the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions):

> When a variable is used in the expressing using the normal ${variable} syntax, its value is replaces before the expression is evaluated. This means that the value used in the expression will be the string representation of the variable value, not the variable value itself. This is not a problem with numbers and other objects that have a string representation that can be evaluated directly, but with other objects the behavior depends on the string representation. Most importantly, strings must always be quoted, and if they can contain newlines, they must be triple quoted.

Assuming that `${GREEN}` contains `green` and `${class}` contains `red`, What this means is that when you do this:

```
Run Keyword If  ${GREEN} == ${class}
```

Python sees this:

```
if green == red
```

Notice that neither `green` nor `red` have quotes around it, since the data itself has no quotes.

The simplest solution is to add your own quotes. (Note: if the value can have newlines or quotes, the safest choice is to use triple quotes)

```
Run Keyword If  '${green}' == '${class}'
```

Comment: How to write >= condition in robot framework?

Comment: @Smash: Just like you would expect: `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you compare directly with a string. why are you storing those colors in a list again?

```
${class}=  Get Element Attribute
Log To Console    ${class}
#I hope you are able to get the exact attribute of that tag(color).


Run Keyword If  '${class}'=='Green'  Keyword green
...  ELSE IF  '${class}'=='Yellow'  Keyword yellow
...  ELSE IF  '${class}'=='Red'  Keyword red
...  ELSE  Keyword gray
```